# React render expected expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting with React at the moment. I followed the official guideline of reactjs.org on how to create a webpage that runs React. Then I just tried to modify the input I was renderung to a simple `<h1>`. However, as soon as I did this, I got unexpected expression error saying that "<" doesn't work.

Here's the code.

```
const element = <h1>test</h1>;

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(element, domContainer);
```

I know this is really basic. Everywhere I looked it worked on their site, but I always get an error.

I used this to import React:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

This is what I wanted to do:
[image]

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: <hi>test</hi>? it should be <h1> right

Comment: Yea sure, but it doesn't change anything, still doesn't work

Comment: do you have an element with #like_button_container ?

Comment: of course I did

Comment: can u add that to your question. Remember your **hi >> h1**
Also post the teminal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because react expect a component to render, it can be a function or a class.

so you must wrap your element as a function or a class and name it with TitleCase.

```
const Element = () => <div>element</div>

ReactDOM.render(<Element />, domContainer);
```

I think you should read more on they documentation [Reactjs Documentation](https://reactjs.org/)

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work. Accroding to reactjs.org it should work like I said

https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

this is where I got the information from

Answer (score 1):

You haven't configured JSX transpilation in your setup. Check this link for using React without JSX: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html.

If you want to use JSX without a setup, add this script to your html: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>` and mark script tags with `type="text/babel"` : 
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx

Although you can add react in a script tag it's not really the recommended way as you need a setup for compiling jsx to js anyway in a real project.

I recommend you use create-react-app for setting up a basic project.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fact that you're "importing" *React* means that you do not use *webpack* or any other building tool. So you do not transpile you code. But

```js
const element = <h1>test</h1>;
```

is not correct JS. It's **JSX**.

Try to change this line to

```js
const element = React.createElement('h1', null, 'test');
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Or use some build toolchain.